# Scaling euler number in Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scaling, eulers-number

I have a pandas dataframe with one column that has euler numbers inside.

E.g.

```
5.589918e+08    
5.572475e+08
8.639290e+09
```

Whats the best way to scale the whole column to normal numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the scientific notation of `Pandas` and is it's way of dealing with very large or small `floats`.

Although not necessary, multiple methods exist if you wish to convert your floats to another format:

**1.** use `apply()`

```
df.apply(lambda x: '%.5f' %x, axis=1)
```

**2.** set the global options of pandas

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.5f' %x)
```

**3.** use `df.round()`. This only works if you have very small numbers with a lot of dcimals

```
df.round(2)
```

Comment: What does the '%.5f' mean ?